# HTML5 : Open PDF in new tab after submitting form

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

Title says all.

I've already tried the two ways I could think of implementing this. First by setting the "action" attribute in the form tag to the PDF url, and second by using some jQuery to simulate a click on a hidden anchor tag linking to an appropriate PDF with the target set to "_blank".

No dice.

Any advice?

Comment: May be your browser is blocking popup to new window/tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('MyPDF.pdf', '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitted by JQuery ?
You could open your pdf after the ajax callback:

```
window.open('/myPDF');
```